# Will this panel fit a C4 for possible onboard PC upgrade?

Tags: citroen, citroen-c4

I have a Citroën C4 2005 Petrol. My central dashboard currently looks like this: 
[image: Citroën C4 2005 Dashboard]

I figured I can buy the following panel from eBay and easily fit a Nexus 7 Tablet inside it, potentially even write an app to get data from OBD2, and even fit the screen inside the glove compartment.

[Here is the eBay listing](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Centre-Dashboard-Facia-Fascia-Panel-Trim-for-Citroen-C4-C-Quatre-C-Triumph-Plate-/271207463493?hash=item3f25397a45:g:jKIAAOSwDk5UAE8K&autorefresh=true)

My idea is to have the tablet as radio, sat-nav, media player, diagnostics etc.

I'm just not entire sure if the panel from eBay would fit my car as it is for a slightly different model C4 even though they look quite alike.

Comment: I'm glad your question is a "fit" question and not a "purchase help" question ... it should be on topic this way. I'm not sure if anyone is going to be able to answer such a specific question, but if they can, I have one similar I want to do with my wife's car. Crossing fingers for a good answer!

Comment: @Paulster2 I'm 95% certain it will fit no problem. Just by looking at them both, one can tell they do look very much the same. But unfortunately my service turned out a bit pricier that i fancied, thus I can't spare even 30$ to try it out.

Comment: You need to measure everything out.  Can't be answered without the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way for me to tell if the attachment system from the back is compatible, but the [eBay listing](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Centre-Dashboard-Facia-Fascia-Panel-Trim-for-Citroen-C4-C-Quatre-C-Triumph-Plate-/271207463493?hash=item3f25397a45:g:jKIAAOSwDk5UAE8K&autorefresh=true) has a very useful image for you shown below.

What you need to do is verify with a ruler or measuring tape that the dimensions between the hazard lights button and corresponding button on the left has a center-to-center length of 240 mm and end-to-end length of 265 mm.

[image: eBay Image]